# Function Bijection if and only if Invertible

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would like to show that a function f:X->X is invertible if and only if it is bijective.

I know it's bijective if and only if it is both surjective and injective, but I am lost as where to go from here.

Comment: What does invertible mean for you?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$\Leftarrow$ In this direction, you need to come up with a function $g$ such that $fg=gf=Id_X$. Given that the bijection pairs elements of $X$ with elements of $X$, try to "reverse" what $f$ does to $X$.

$\Rightarrow$ Here we show that $f$ is injective. Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$. Can you get what you want using the inverse function?

Now show $f$ is surjective: given $y\in X$, try to find something sent to $y$. Look at $f(f^{-1}(y))=y$.

Comment: I think it should be "Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$ ..."

Comment: @StefanHamcke Urgh, yes, I totally lost the thread while tablet-typing. I fixed it to be non-stupid now. Thanks!